# How to add custom libraries and binaries in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-3.6

I have deployed my app with python36 runtime long ago, and now AWS Deprecated this runtime.

So while migrating from python36 to python38 or python39, I observed that AWS removed many in-built libraries in Amazon Linux 2 which is used for Python38 or python39.

Here we need to add binaries if we're using them in our App.

how to add custom binaries to the lambda package? Suggest ways to do it, if you know.

References:

- [AWS Lambda Deprecation Schedules](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html#runtime-support-policy)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need?

Comment: I need to make binaries like file, tar etc available to my app in lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with python3.8, AWS Lambda removed many Binaries like tar, find file, cat, which etc.

So if you're using any of these binaries in our package, we can add them using layers.

#### Method 1:

Add libraries in layers in the custom directory, and let lambda know the directory by setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH environment Variables.

Let's say you've added your binaries in `custom_bins` directory then you've to set `PATH` as `/var/lang/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin/:/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/custom_bins`

and if you've added your custom libraries in `custom_libs` directory then you've to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as `/var/lang/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/var/runtime:/var/runtime/lib:/var/task:/var/task/lib:/opt/lib:/opt/custom_libs`

#### Method 2:

By Default, Lambda will detect libraries in the `/opt/lib` path and binaries in `/opt/bin`, as we know layers will be available in `/opt`  directory, we can create a layer with `/lib` and `/bin` directories containing appropriate libraries & binaries.

Layer Structure:

```
custom_libs/
├── bin
│   ├── curl
│   └── bin_2
│   └── bin_3
└── lib
    ├── libbz2.so.1
    ├── lib_2
    ├── lib_3
    └── magic
```

Here, we need not set any environment variables as we uploaded our libraries & binaries in the path detected by lambda by default.

> Note: If your binaries require a magic file then you can add a magic file and specify a magic file path using the `MAGIC` environment variable.